# How to set minimum diameter in jfxtras CircularPane?

Tags: java, javafx, jfxtras

How to set minimum diameter to jfxtras circularpane. For example take a look at following code,

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jfxtras.scene.layout.*;

/**
 * AssistiveBall
 */
public class AssistiveBall extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage pStage) throws Exception 
    {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        CircularPane pane = new CircularPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        Button btn = new Button("Center");
        Button[] buttons = new Button[13];

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = new Button("" + i);
        }

        pane.getChildren().addAll(buttons);

        btn.setOnAction(e -> {
            if(pane.isVisible())
            {
                pane.setVisible(false);
            }
            else
            {
                pane.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        pStage.setScene(scene);
        pStage.setTitle("Assistive Ball");
        pStage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        AssistiveBall.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here here code if fine, but if i use just 3 buttons it starts appear one on another, So how to set minimum diameter or there is any another way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which package is CircularPane from? I can't find any javadocs [here](https://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-common/index.html).

Comment: Yup mee to i can't find javadoc so i have look ar source file for doc https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras/blob/11/jfxtras-common/src/main/java/jfxtras/scene/layout/CircularPane.java

Comment: From looking at the code I cannot find a way to set minimal size. However, if you have the code you could inherit CircularPane in a new class and patch whatever is necessary to implement the logic. A very naive approach would be to override `determineBeadDiameter(MinPrefMax size)` but the author chose to make it private. My suggestion is to fork the project on GitHub and modify the latter method. Then you can send a pull request to the author and push it upstream.

Comment: In `determineBeadDiameter` you could check if the return value is < than whatever you deem to be reasonable, then fix it at this minimum value.

Comment: Of course you provide the change as a pull request. ;-) But it is an interesting suggestion. I can always make the method not private.

Comment: Something similar can be achieved by overriding computeChainDiameter. I'll start making some methods protected, so they can be overridden in an extending class.

Answer (score 0):

Version 11-r3-SNAPSHOT has changed certain methods like computeChainDiameter and determineBeadDiameter to protected, so you can override them and tune the output.